# JS send FormData to Flask API but the API got empty data

Tags: javascript, python, flask, multipartform-data

The js I used to send a POST request

```js
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('textData', 'somestring');
formData.append('file', File object);
const request = {
      method: "POST",
      body: formData,
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'},
      };
const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8001/upload_files', request);
```

I can assure the `formData` object contains the data

My Python Flask API

```py
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/upload_files', methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin()
def upload_files():
    print(request.form)
    print(request.files)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='localhost', port=8001)
```

The print from the API function

```
ImmutableMultiDict([])
ImmutableMultiDict([])
```

The API can receive the POST request from the js but did not receive the data and file. How can I solve this problem? Many thanks!

Comment: Don't set the content type manually. It is automatically set based on the FormData object. Then your code should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The POST request works after I remove the content type. The content type is automatically set based on the FormData object

```
const request = {
      method: "POST",
      body: formData,
      };
```